# "Containers" tag vs "Potting" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I think the Container tag is ambiguous with the Potting tag.  Also (IMO) the container tag more accurately describes plants growing anywhere but inside the ground (eg 'contained' environments) better than potting which brings to mind clay pots and not something like a windowsill planter.

Is there a way to merge potting into container to help search results return ?

Comment: There is a large subset of gardening that is done in "containers" and its called "container gardening" this is what is sometimes meant by the [tag:container] tag

Comment: @waxeagle: Unless anyone objects, can you merge potting -> containers when you have a chance?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, as wax eagle mentions in a comment, [containers](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/containers) is intended for "container gardening" (growing in pots).

There's a lot of overlap between [containers](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/containers) and [potting](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/potting) -- it might be appropriate to make one a synonym of the other. I'm not sure I can think of a useful distinction between the two tags. (IMO, containers would be a better master.)

Comment: Editted question to go in the direction of your second paragraph.